# Construction convention for multiple if method

Tags: c++

I wounder if there is some construction convention for constructing method with multiple if's. Most of the time before you fire your method you have to check input arguments and other things, eg. is not nullptr, is > 0, is != -1 etc. Sometimes you cannot check this in one if and as a result you have something like this:

```
if(arg != nullptr)
{
    if()
    {
        if()
        {
            if()
            {
                /*actual code here*/
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* other error message like "License check error: wrong key!" */
    }
}
else
{
    /* wrong input args! */
}
```

Good convention is that your line has less than 80 characters which gives us less space for actual code. Code is getting more and more unreadable.

Comment: At least in the case of resource management, the classic resolution of the "triangle of death" anti-pattern is the use of RAII. You might be able to devise some classes with RAII-like functionality of which the destructors, combined with early returns, manage errors in a similar fashion. Depending on your actual needs, even early returns by themselves may be enough.

Comment: Don't be too worried about only having one `return` statement: test for each error condition and return if it's a fail.  Also, testing for things such as a null pointer are fairly pointless except where your code has an external interface and the parameters are beyond your control.  In safety critical systems unreachable code is not allowed, meaning that unless `null` is a valid value it shouldn't be tested for, because if it's invalid you'll never pass it!

Comment: From your skeleton code, I am assuming that you want to do something based upon the arguments received (?). In that case better to create a map of expected argument(s) to a callback function which will do the stuff as per your if-else condition.

Comment: @MikeofSST So it is pointless having only one return? Company where i've been working use this code rule (or I misunderstand this).

Comment: @Isaac It is usually a good practice guideline, rather than a hard rule.  In most cases having only one `return` makes the code more readable and guards against things like mismatched `malloc` and `free`.  In some instances, like the instance in your question, it is counter-productive.  I expect that a company with good coding conventions, like yours, will also have a policy for handling exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return early in the case of issues, or throw an exception:

```
if(arg == nullptr) {
    log("arg was null, not doing anything");
    return;
}

//if the user forgot to make the toast, we can do it for them
if(forgotToMakeToast) {
    makeToast();
}

if(ranOverDog) {
    //we can't continue if the user ran over our dog, throw an exception
    throw too_angry_exception;
}

//actual code
```

This makes your code structure more obvious by relating the error handling to the error checking by locality.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is something like this:

```
if(arg == nullptr)
{
    /* wrong input args! */
    return;
}


if()
{
    /* other error message like "License check error: wrong key!" */
    return;
}

...


/*actual code here*/
```

Then you have all your error "ifs" and error handling in one place, and the actual function code at the end, nicely separated.

Comment: So it is pointless having only one return? Company where i've been working use this code rule (or I misunderstand this).

Comment: @Isaac It depends on your code, but I don't see a general reason to only have one return. (They main reason I could see is doing some "cleanup" work that should happen in all cases, even in error cases. However, with RAII this is not an issue)

Answer (score 0):

When you have too many sub-levels of `if`, `while`, `for` in a function, it is a sign that the function should be split into 2 or more separate functions. Depending on specific code it could look something like this:

```
public void MyClass::Run(arg)
{
    if(arg != nullptr)
    {
        if()
        {
            RunActualCode()
        }
        else
        {
            /* other error message like "License check error: wrong key!" */
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* wrong input args! */
    }
}

private void MyClass::RunActualCode(...)
{
    if()
    {
        if()
        {
            /*actual code here*/
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

There are many recommendation about this, for example:

> Rec 4.7 Do not have too complex functions.
>
> Everyone that has ever had to take over code written by someone else
>   knows that complex code is hard to maintain. There are many ways in
>   which a function can be complex, such as the number of lines of code,
>   the number of parameters, or the number of possible paths through a
>   function. The number of possible paths through a function, which is
>   the result from the use of many control flow primitives, is the main
>   reason to why functions are complex. Therefore you should be aware of
>   the fact that heavy use of control flow primitives will make your code
>   more difficult to maintain.
>   http://www.tiobe.com/content/paperinfo/CodingStandards/hem/industrial/bookindex.htm

[Limiting complexity during development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity#Limiting_complexity_during_development)

Answer (score 0):

Your original construction could be written like this:

```
do
{
    if(nullptr == arg) // Note: *negate* your original conditions!
    {
        /* wrong input args! */
        break;
    }
    if(...)
    {
        /* other error message like "License check error: wrong key!" */
        break;
    }
    if(...)
    {
        ...
        break;
    }
    if(...)
    {
        ...
        break;
    }

    /*actual code here*/

} while (0);
```

- Advantages:

  1. no nested `if`s;
  2. use `break` instead of `goto` to jump out of the whole block;
  3. the logic is clearer, and more maintainable: if you want to add a check guard, just append one more `if(...){...; break;}`;
- Disadvantages:

  1. `do-while(0)` looks a bit strange;
  2. you should negate all your original conditions, e.g. `if(cond)` => `if(!cond)`, which may affect the code clarity;